# How to dynamically select dataframe in Rshiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I want to dynamically select the dataframe in Rshiny.

This is what I have:

```
## First we are going to import some example dataframes
Biomarker <- read_excel("C:\\Datasets\\Example1.xlsx")
Baseline <- read_excel("C:\\Datasets\\Example2.xlsx")
Mutation <- read_excel("C:\\Datasets\\Example3.xlsx")

# We are going to create a list of this dataframes so we can select which one we want in the Rshiny app
ldf <- list(Biomarker = Biomarker, Baseline = Baseline, Mutation = Mutation)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset", ldf),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  tableOutput("table")
)
```

But this in fact allows you to pick the rows inside the dataframe, not the dataframe itself.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data and you are missing the server side, so I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong with your code. But a really simple way to change dataframes in a renderTable is just to use an if else statement based on the choice in the selectInput, like so:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset", choices = c("mtcars", "starwars", "iris")),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table<-renderTable({
   if(input$dataset == "mtcars") {
      mtcars
    } else if (input$dataset == "starwars") {
      starwars[1:5]
    } else if (input$dataset == "iris") {
      iris
    }
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```